# Regex to return true only if the specified string is present

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to match "Test"

```
var regex = new RegExp('^((?!Test).)*$')
regex.test('Test')
```

However, this does not work.

I need a regex that will return true only when the specified string is present.

Comment: If you want to return true when 'Test' is present, try regex `^Test$`? or even just `Test`? You currently seem to be looking for when the word "Test" is *not* present, by virtue of the negative lookahead `(!?...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would just be `^Test$`, but you could also do `string === 'Test'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if a string is present, try just `Test`. With JavaScript, you could do `str.indexOf("Test") != -1`. If you want to test if the string is only test, use `^Test$` or `str === "Test"`.

Comment: `"Testicles".indexOf("Test")`

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on assertions to test for a word's presence:

```
/(?=\bTest\b)/.test('I want to Test this')
// true

/(?=\bTest\b)/.test('I want to Fail this')
// false
```